# Trouble referencing highchart.js in Meteor application

Tags: highcharts, meteor

I am trying to use highcharts.js in a Meteor.js application but can't get past the initial referencing errors. My console is showing the following:

Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type    text/html:   "http://`localhost`:3000/highcharts.js". localhost:9     Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < :3000/highcharts.js:1     Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null    highcharts.js:55

I have the highchart.js file in my client/lib directory and my highchart javascript code in my app.js file in the client directory. I have tried moving the highchart.js file to other locations, but it has dom references that are a problem when in server scope, so ended up in my client/lib directory.

Any thoughts on how to resolve this initial configuration/reference problem would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you referencing this manually? (Putting in <script> in your html file?)

Comment: I have tried a couple different ways, putting <script> tags in html file and then just putting the javascript in my app.js file, but get the same error either way. I am not sure if this is a configuration issue or a problem with meteor interacting with the highcharts.js file?

Comment: Update: I was calling the function before the Dom was available, so that caused the innerHTML = null error, the others were related to another .js file in my meteor project.

Comment: So you have added on DOM ready and everything works fine?

Comment: Yes, working very well now after checking DOM ready. I did have an another problem with the chart rendering, but I did a container.refresh() and all was good. This problem was also fixed in the latest version of the highcharts.js (version 3.0.) Thanks again!