# Can't create gauge charts using HighCharts

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, charts, highcharts

I'm currently using meteor to create a gauge charts,
I have copied the demo code from [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/gauge-vu-meter/), and here's my code:

```
<template name="Charts">

<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"</script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/solid-gauge.js"></script>


<div id="container" style="width: 600px; height: 300px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

<script>
    $(function () {
        $('#container').highcharts({

                    chart: {
                        type: 'gauge',
                        plotBorderWidth: 1,
                        plotBackgroundColor: {
                            linearGradient: { x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1 },
                            stops: [
                                [0, '#FFF4C6'],
                                [0.3, '#FFFFFF'],
                                [1, '#FFF4C6']
                            ]
                        },
                        plotBackgroundImage: null,
                        height: 200
                    },

                    title: {
                        text: 'VU meter'
                    },

                    pane: [{
                        startAngle: -45,
                        endAngle: 45,
                        background: null,
                        center: ['25%', '145%'],
                        size: 300
                    }, {
                        startAngle: -45,
                        endAngle: 45,
                        background: null,
                        center: ['75%', '145%'],
                        size: 300
                    }],

                    tooltip: {
                        enabled: false
                    },

                    yAxis: [{
                        min: -20,
                        max: 6,
                        minorTickPosition: 'outside',
                        tickPosition: 'outside',
                        labels: {
                            rotation: 'auto',
                            distance: 20
                        },
                        plotBands: [{
                            from: 0,
                            to: 6,
                            color: '#C02316',
                            innerRadius: '100%',
                            outerRadius: '105%'
                        }],
                        pane: 0,
                        title: {
                            text: 'VU<br/><span style="font-size:8px">Channel A</span>',
                            y: -40
                        }
                    }, {
                        min: -20,
                        max: 6,
                        minorTickPosition: 'outside',
                        tickPosition: 'outside',
                        labels: {
                            rotation: 'auto',
                            distance: 20
                        },
                        plotBands: [{
                            from: 0,
                            to: 6,
                            color: '#C02316',
                            innerRadius: '100%',
                            outerRadius: '105%'
                        }],
                        pane: 1,
                        title: {
                            text: 'VU<br/><span style="font-size:8px">Channel B</span>',
                            y: -40
                        }
                    }],

                    plotOptions: {
                        gauge: {
                            dataLabels: {
                                enabled: false
                            },
                            dial: {
                                radius: '100%'
                            }
                        }
                    },


                    series: [{
                        name: 'Channel A',
                        data: [-20],
                        yAxis: 0
                    }, {
                        name: 'Channel B',
                        data: [-20],
                        yAxis: 1
                    }]

                },

                // Let the music play
                function (chart) {
                    setInterval(function () {
                        if (chart.series) { // the chart may be destroyed
                            var left = chart.series[0].points[0],
                                    right = chart.series[1].points[0],
                                    leftVal,
                                    rightVal,
                                    inc = (Math.random() - 0.5) * 3;

                            leftVal = left.y + inc;
                            rightVal = leftVal + inc / 3;
                            if (leftVal < -20 || leftVal > 6) {
                                leftVal = left.y - inc;
                            }
                            if (rightVal < -20 || rightVal > 6) {
                                rightVal = leftVal;
                            }

                            left.update(leftVal, false);
                            right.update(rightVal, false);
                            chart.redraw();
                        }
                    }, 500);

                });
    });
</script>

</template>
```

However, it shows ***Error: Highcharts error #17: www.highcharts.com/errors/17***:This error happens when you are setting chart.type or series.type to a series type that isn't defined in Highcharts. A typical reason may be that your are missing the extension file where the series type is defined, for example in order to run an arearange series you need to load the highcharts-more.js file.

And I am pretty sure those files(include jQuery) are properly loaded on the webpage.

Is there anything I missed?

Comment: What happens if you change the `http` to `https` for the `solid-gauge.js` script? I wonder whether that one's not getting through due to your site's security/proxy configuration.

Comment: @brightmatrix Nothing happened :( Thanks anyway.

Comment: OK, it's good to at least rule that out. I copied all of your code into a fiddle and it works exactly as expected. Are you trying to produce a different *kind* of gauge, such as this one: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/gauge-speedometer?

Comment: @brightmatrix Yes I have tried. Actually every dynamic graph(with updating values) does not work on my app.

Comment: Hmm, that's puzzling. Are you getting any obvious errors in your console?

Comment: @brightmatrix No nothing on my server side. And for the client side, just that Error#17

Comment: Have you tried to use Highcharts in that way: http://www.highcharts.com/blog/195-meteor-standalone ?

Answer (score 0):

From what I could research, the `<template>` tag is your problem. You mentioned that you had problems with "dynamic graphs." This page I found on the `<template>` tag says the following (in the "Declaring template content" section):

> The HTML  element represents a template in your markup. It
>   contains "template contents"; essentially **inert chunks of cloneable
>   DOM.** Think of templates as pieces of scaffolding that you can use (and
>   reuse) throughout the lifetime of your app.

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/template/

To me, that reads that anything in between those `<template>` tags needs to be static HTML only and cannot be dynamic content such as scripts or the gauge charts you're trying to use.

Move all of your scripts outside of the `<template>` tags and see if that fixes your problem.

Comment: Well, I have move all of the <script> out of <template> and created a <body> to place them. The error 17 disappeared but still showing nothing.

Comment: Are you still working in your fiddle, or your site code? If you can show me more of where you're placing the chart code, that might help. Moving the scripts outside the `<template>` tag and putting them in `<body>` in the fiddle didn't cause a problem (see http://jsfiddle.net/brightmatrix/jexhe996/3/).

Comment: I'm working on my site code. I have tried moving script to a new JS file, putting script in a <body> tag, and put it on meteor's template helper. But none of them worked.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Meteor, so I unfortunately can't help you with issues in that environment. I did find two posts that may be helpful for you: 1) http://forum.highcharts.com/highstock-usage/not-able-to-use-highstock-with-meteor-t34606/ and 2) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16637724/trouble-referencing-highchart-js-in-meteor-application